# fetch key string from website

Tags: python

I need to fetch "status" key from:
`https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=****&api_secret=****&from=test&to=number&text=Welcome` content.
and return the status key number.
the content of the url if the sms sent:

```
{"message-count":"1","messages":[{"to":"192182","message-id":"23323046C","status":"0","remaining-balance":"1000.92000000","message-price":"0.01500000","network":"42232303"}]}
```

if the status key == 0 the sms was sent, otherwise there was an error sending the sms.

from nexmo docs:

```
0   Delivered
1   Unknown
2   Absent Subscriber - Temporary
3   Absent Subscriber - Permanent
4   Call barred by user
5   Portability Error
6   Anti-Spam Rejection
7   Handset Busy
8   Network Error
9   Illegal Number
10  Invalid Message
11  Unroutable
12  Destination Un-Reachable
```

please, can anyone tell me how I can get the number of the status key as string using python. So, after that I can make code to give my users the status of the sms if it's equal to 0 or not.

Thank you.

Comment: that's a json response. decode the json to a native python structure, then access the data like you would with any other python structure.

Comment: so its lok like  

`import json
import urllib2

# Open the URL and the screen name
url = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=****&api_secret=****&from=test&to=number&text=Welcome"

# This takes a python object and dumps it to a string which is a JSON representation of that object
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

#print the result
print data`  

But now how i can get the status key string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple code sample to accomplish this task:

```
import json
import requests

STATUS_MESSAGES = (
    'Delivered',
    'Unknown',
    'Absent Subscriber - Temporary',
    'Absent Subscriber - Permanent',
    'Call barred by user',
    'Portability Error',
    'Anti-Spam Rejection',
    'Handset Busy',
    'Network Error',
    'Illegal Number',
    'Invalid Message',
    'Unroutable',
    'Destination Un-Reachable')

data = json.loads(requests.get('http://your/url').text)
print STATUS_MESSAGES[int(data['messages'][0]['status'])]
```

It makes the assumption that you transmit messages one at a time. If you were to transmit several messages at once you would need to iterate over all the elements in `data['messages']` and fetch their status.

Comment: Not sure how this particular API works but this could also risk an `IndexError` on certain error conditions (if `data['messages']` is empty).